# AWS Automated Testing - SNS SQS Lambda DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serenity-bdd

I have a setup like SNS -> SQS -> Lambda. The lambda function will save a file to S3 and save an item in DynamoDB

Now I would like to have an automated test case for it which I'm using Serenity

What I'm having so far are

1. The program test will send a SNS.
2. The program test will ***wait and wait*** until a file on S3 generated and DynamoDB item is created
3. The program will download the file from S3 and verify it
4. The program will verify the entry in DynamoDB and verify it

The problem here is at step #2, I have to keep waiting and waiting in X minutes (the same as time out of the lambda function).

Please advice me if we have a better approach and a solution to solve the "wait" at step #2.

Thanks,

Comment: Suggestions I can think of begin to get over-engineered and somewhat convoluted rather quickly... but I would suggest that *initially* querying dynamo while waiting might be a better approach than querying S3, because S3 has a known behavior of negatively-caching responses to requests for non-existent objects -- a case of the "observer effect" -- requesting an object before it exists *may* delay its eventual appearance because S3 has temporarily optimized-away lookups of the object because some internal component of S3 "knows" the object "doesn't" (extrapolation from *didn't*) exist.

Comment: Otherwise you'll need the Lambda function, or a bucket event, or a DynamoDB Streama event to somehow push a notification back to you via a channel you'll be watching, right?  Creating such a channel for the purpose of the test seems to make the entire process more fragile, since the code now needs to perform actions unnecessary except for the benefit of the test environment.  Or, I may be overlooking something or misunderstanding your objective.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot. I don't think I will update the lambda to communicate back to channel  cuz it is just for test as you said. it is not actually the function of the lambda. Waiting for more advice from team here

Answer (score 0):

What if the lambda was designed to queue a message when it completes. The test and actual consumers could then "listen" for messages on the response queue to know when the output is ready to test.

Test could use the SQS long polling API for the response message.